# grunt-contrib-compass doesn't execute task

Tags: xcode, gruntjs, compass, grunt-contrib-compass

I recently changed my mac. I used to worked with grunt and grunt-contrib-compass without issues but since i changed, compass doesn't work anymore.

I installed every tools i needed (ruby, compass, sass, xcode, command line tools, grunt ,etc ..) and kept the same gruntfile.js and configuration. When i run grunt, every task are executabe, even compass, but grunt-contrib-compass do nothing, it show this :

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
//nothing
Running "csslint:dev" (csslint) task
>>1 file lint free.
// csslint, like the others plugins, works fine
```

The issue doesn't from my grunt configuration because in the same folder, grunt-contrib-compass work in my old mac.

I noticed xcodebuild doesn't run during grunt's execution.

Any idea where is my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed both Compass and SASS?

You should not install SASS if you have installed Compass:

```
// * for Compass, run `npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-compass` 
//   This depends on the ruby compass gem, which can be installed with
//   `gem install compass`
//   You should not install SASS if you have installed Compass.
```